# EF core: one-to-one with one-to-many

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In my model there is for one account many subscriptions, but just one subscription is active.

so, I tried model like that:

```
public virtual DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .HasOne(p => p.ActiveSubscription)
            .WithOne(i => i.ActiveInAccount)
            .HasForeignKey<Subscription>(b => b.ActiveInAccountForeignKey);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Subscriptions)
            .WithOne(i => i.Account)
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.AccountId);
     }

 public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
    public Subscription ActiveSubscription { get; set; }
}

public class Subscription
{
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public int? ActiveInAccountForeignKey { get; set; }
    public Account ActiveInAccount { get; set; }
}
```

now I tried post new account with activeSubscription, and non-active subscription. if I post this json:

```
{
  "accountId": 0,
  "subscriptions": [
    {
      "subscriptionId": 0,
      "name": "nonActive",
      "accountId": 0,
      "activeInAccountForeignKey": null
    }
  ],
  "activeSubscription": {
      "subscriptionId": 0,
      "name": "active",
      "accountId": 0,
      "activeInAccountForeignKey": 0
  }
}
```

Then new account created with some id (for example 5). 
Additionally - automatically "nonActive" subscription has `accountId` 5 and "active" subscription has  `activeInAccountForeignKey` 5 and `accountId` 0. 
I want that active subscription `accountId` also will be 5 automatically.

How can I achieve that (or: how should look my model)?

Thanks!

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I'm not sure I undearstand you. How can I have this one-to-one relationship without ActiveInAccount? I use https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#one-to-one example to create this relationship. When I tried use "Account Account" for both many-to-one and one-to-one relationships I'm got exception that I can use it just for one relationship

Comment: The code that processes the json is where it's all happening. What does it look like?

Comment: @GertArnold Something like: public void Post(Account account){context. Accounts. Add(account); context saveChanges)

Comment: Yeah, well, you don't add `activeSubscription` to the account's `Subscriptions`. How would EF know it belongs there?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the following scenario is not possible: A `Subscription` object's parent `Account` is different than the `ActiveInAccount`.

If that is the case (and hopefully that is) then you can get rid of the `ActiveInAccount`, and `ActiveInAccountForeignKey` in `Subscription`, and `ActiveSubscription` in `Account`. For active subscription you can simply use `bool IsActive` in `Subscription`, to denote active subscription. And based on this, you can redesign your entity model.

Apart from this, you must also think about how your entities are related, whether it is one-to-one, one-to-many, or many-to-many for example. In my experience, I have never seen two entities that are related with each other with more than one relationship, for any good reason. Maybe a good starting point would be to start with a simple class diagram, and decide the cardinalities/relationship between these classes. And from there start writing your entity model.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting cart before the horse. Create model without considerations "how it would look in web api?" Just create the model.

When model created you can try to utilize automatically generated WebAPI, ODATA or other API. In case you need something special - then you  need to transform your model classes to your custom structures manually.